# Slow down CSS Opacity Animation

Tags: css, performance, animation, opacity, css-transitions

I want to slow down animation timing in .opacity CSS property.
Like, i want it to delay 0.2ms or something like that.

To get a better idea, opacity is added when hovered a featured post on my site here: http://www.thetechnodaily.com

Remember: I have NOT USED jQuery in this. Its pure CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions).

Transitions allow you to set a [delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transition-delay) and the [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transition-duration) of the transition.

Answer (score 5):

I think this might be what you are trying to achieve?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/9VB72/2/

[More info](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp)

Comment: Note: Putting the transition in the hover rule will only provide the transition one-way.  If you put it in the main rule, it will transition both ways.

Comment: 1 minus point because of expired link

Answer (score 1):

**Using jquery**

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
   $('#book').animate({
       opacity: 0.25,
       left: '+=50',
       height: 'toggle'
   }, 5000, function() {
     // Animation complete.
   });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Using **css** you can try something like this:

```
.class:hover {
    opacity: 1; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;  /* FF4+ */
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;  /* IE10? */
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;  
}
```